# When Save As Image get watermark or blank image

Tags: jquery, image, drupal, watermark, galleria

I'm using Galleria Fullscreen theme. Put that js code in my main js file for don't right click:

```
$('img').live('contextmenu', function(e){
return false;
});
```

But don't work on IE Windows. So, i want when save as image get watermark or blank image. Because my images very important and want to strong protect.

How can i do?

Comment: You CAN'T protect your images on the web. The moment the users sees an image in his browser, he already downloaded it to his computer... If you really want to protect your images, don't expose them. (to be more constructive: you can't deliver material, which you don't want to hand to the user - you have to restrict it already on serverside - e.g. put the watermark on your images BEFORE delivery)

Answer (score 0):

If you want watermarks on them, put watermarks on the externally and only serve up watermarked images to clients. Any solution that uses javascript will not work as the user can simply turn off javascript.